# Is "crevice" an abstract or concrete noun?

Tags: nouns

I can't find an answer to this question that my students and I are debating about. Is *crevice* an abstract or concrete noun?

Comment: IF it's a crevice in concrete, it must be abstract, since if it were concrete there would be no crevice, right? :)

Comment: Silence is music.

Comment: If it is something that you can perceive with your senses, it is concrete.

Answer (score 5):

You're perhaps puzzled because a crevice is an empty space, but it's still a feature of the real world and so it's a concrete noun.

Comment: Thanks for your help; it makes sense to see it as a feature of the real world.

Comment: @Barrie England: Can you give an authority to support that assertion? _Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus_ has:  'a noun that refers to a thing that does not exist as a material object' which certainly classes 'crevice' as abstract.

Comment: Afraid not. I know of no dictionary or similar work that classifies nouns in this way. Would you say ‘hole’ was an abstract noun? I wouldn’t, and I say that ‘crevice’ isn’t for the same reason. 

Here’s what Katie Wales says in ‘A Dictionary of Stylisitcs’: ‘Abstract nouns are a subclass of nouns which refer to qualities or states, i.e. they have non-material reference’. Crucially, to my mind, she says ‘they lack the number and article contrast of concrete nouns’. We cannot, to take her examples, say *eagernesses’ or *’a bravery’, but we can say ‘a crevice’ and ‘crevices’.

Comment: I think this is beginning to sound like one of many treatments that don't really address underlying concepts, but seek to bodge a semanto-syntactic approach. 'Day' and 'night' are considered abstract nouns (at least here: http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/wmbaskervill/bl-wmbaskervill-grammar-parts-nouns.htm ) but are indisputably count. 'Shadow', 'winter' and 'lightning' are also classed here as _abstract_ - I'd say the first two may be count or uncount, and all three are more or less perceivable by senses, but intangible. I've found a better working model:

Comment: In the thread at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124470/is-there-an-english-dictionary-that-distinguishes-words-as-either-abstract-or-co/124503#124503 , I mention the 'Four orders of entities' Lyons, and Hengeveld, suggest to replace the 'concrete / abstract' classification. I think I'd want, just after 'concrete', a class 'perceived _indirectly_ by the senses - framed by concrete surroundings etc' for holes / pauses / shadows... . I'm still working on 'flame', 'rainbow'....

Comment: I think there may be a need to review all the terms and categories used to describe English grammar, but I wonder if the abstract / concrete (and common / proper) distinction is really of much importance. Still, that's too big a topic to pursue here.

Comment: It's not good to divorce syntax from meaning for long, and meaning (of lexical as opposed to structural words) must look at the nature of referents and the concepts involved in describing them. One partially valid argument against describing the class of nouns, say, semantically is that the woefully inadequate 'definition' "a noun is the name (or word-coding) of any person, place or thing" is almost useless. (see eg http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2012/06/20/being-a-noun/ ) However, totally syntactic definitions distance language from its purpose of describing the real world.

Comment: I'll correct an earlier statement of mine: 'Day' and 'night' are [at least by some authorities] considered abstract nouns (reference given) but are indisputably count [on occasion]: 'Three nights had passed without the sky being clear enough to use the telescope.' 'I'm having one of those days.' However, non-count usages are common: 'They are not active during the day.'

Comment: Do you have a LinkedIn account? If so, you might like to know that I've posted the question 'What is an abstract noun?' in the group Grammar Geeks http://tinyurl.com/qddmjzp

Answer (score 3):

"[Abstract nouns:](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/abstractnoun.htm) You cannot *see* them, *hear* them, *smell* them, *taste* them, or *feel* them."

My rock-climbing friends find crevices to be wonderfully concrete...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was referring to vertical climbing, not horizontal...