# Is there an English dictionary that distinguishes words as either abstract or concrete?

Tags: nouns

The words that express the tangible and visible things of our experience, such as *sand* or *sea*, are all nouns, as are those expressing intangibles such as *love* or *idealism*.

Also, some nouns, like *field* or *grain*, can be imagined both as tangible and intangible.

People, generally, refer to these nouns with the terms *concrete* (tangible) and *abstract* (intangible).

That being said, my question is, is there an English dictionary that—as well as identifying a word as a noun—additionally identifies the noun as either “abstract” or “concrete”? Are there any other resources that do this?

Comment: Could you start by distinguishing them yourself? What do you mean by _abstract_ and _concrete_? Could you give us some examples?

Comment: Different terms can mean different things to different people. I was taught at school that some nouns can be "concrete" (like *chair*) and some "abstract" (like *beauty*). Others may have different terms for that distinction. If that's the distinction you meant, please say so.

Comment: Also please chill out a little, your question is not clear since it is the concepts that the words represent that can be abstract or concrete and this is not a grammatical but a semantic difference. I asked for a clarification to be able to help you better and you replied with a rude comment. That is not how we expect users to behave here.

Comment: The reason (since apparently you need one other than being asked politely) is that people who know the answer you seek might _not_ know how you're defining the distinction in question, avenues you've already pursued, etc. It may be as simple as including [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_and_concrete) if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Is there an English dictionary that list a noun as either abstract noun or concrete noun? The same way a dictionary list a word as either noun, verb, or adjective?

Comment: English is a money language and need to learn it to make money. This is a second language for me.

Comment: We know it is not your first language, that is a good reason to excuse the mistakes in your question, it is no reason to excuse your rudeness however. Also, if you had taken the time to check what this site is [about] you would have realized that it is not designed to help people who are learning English. You might want to check out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) but they won;t help you either unless you can be civil.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit based on comments. It could be improved further with discrete examples of each based on what you have been taught of each type so far. But it probably does belong on English Language Learners.

Comment: If you mean countable vs. uncountable/mass, then pretty much every dictionary will contain that information. If you mean something else, you must clarify what you mean, or at the very least what you need it for. As you can see, there are any number of people who are not familiar with the terms *and yet are fluent in the language*, so chances are you don't need it either and should focus on stuff that actually matters. Again, hard to tell without knowing what you actually have in mind.

Comment: @Andrew, since, as always, I agree with you, I edited the question in order to have a more expanded explanation in reference to how it is possible distinguishing abstract and concrete nouns.

Comment: @Andrew, as the question is now posed, I don't think it belongs to ELL. In fact, perhaps, we need a complex answer here.

Answer (score 3):

In English, "concrete" and "abstract" are not grammatical classifications. This is unlike (for example) "masculine" and "feminine" in French, and "uncountable" and "countable" in English. For both of these cases, there are nouns which one might think are masculine (or countable) from their meaning, but actually are feminine (or uncountable). For example, you can ask why "peas" are countable but "rice" is uncountable. Or in French, why is it "le cigar" but "la pipe". There's no real reason; it's just grammar.

However, anybody can sort nouns into "concrete" and "abstract" based on their definitions, and nobody will be able to say that they did it incorrectly. Since there isn't a definitive classification, dictionaries don't give it.

Comment: '"[U]ncountable" and "countable" [nouns] in English [are grammatical classifications]'. True. I think it's worth pointing out that such usage may accord with or fly in the face of logic: '...mass nouns such as "water" or "furniture", with which only singular verb forms are used because the [term used] is 'grammatically nondiscrete' (although [the referent] may {"water"} or may not {"furniture"} be etically nondiscrete).' [Wikipedia, 'mass noun', modified] [and notice that the 'because' is misused, as it introduces a paraphrase rather than a real explanation]

Comment: There **is** a reason why "peas" are countable but "rice" not. Do you know the German term "Erbsenzähler"? ;)

Comment: At the risk of being labelled a nit-picker (my son is a bean-counter), I'll venture: that should be 'pea' _is_ countable. Although I'd ask for 'less peas', especially if they were mushy. (A _real_ pedant would add that 'rice' _can_ be.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really predicated on the assumption that the abstract / concrete partition of nouns is accepted as axiomatic.

That there is still a lot of analysis to be done is evident from the fact that there are only about 7 distinct Google hits for the term 'second order noun'. However, from one of them is the following:

> **Four orders of entities:**
>
> Lyons (1977...) presents a three-way typology of entities, which
> refines the traditional distinction between concrete and abstract
> nouns...
>
> Entities of the first order are physical objects, i.e. persons,
> animals and things...
>
> Entities of the second order are events, processes, states-of-affairs
> etc...[arrival, error...]
>
> Entities of the third order are such abstract entities as propositions
> [beliefs, ideas...]
>
> [and Hengeveld postulates a fourth order:]
>
> Entities of the fourth order are speech acts [question, command...]
>
> (
> http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=l7UWMZq7FGIC&pg=PR13&lpg=PR13&dq=%22second+order+noun%22&source=bl&ots=bm-uk-g8Dh&sig=ilf32ju-4MT2pVAlBz5qUcuyyMk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZdAfUszWOuir7AaJ4oCgCg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22second%20order%20noun%22&f=false
> )

I still wouldn't be happy to include 'hole', 'vacuum'... in any of these categories.

See [Is "12:30" (the time of day) an abstract noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104371/is-1230-the-time-of-day-an-abstract-noun) .

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to provide a list, as some words can be tangible and intangible, dependent on the context.

e.g.

> The chair presided over the meeting.
>   The chair is in the kitchen.

In the first sentence, the chair refers to someones position or title, which is intangible.
In the second, the chair is a physical object that you sit upon, which makes it tangible.

English is a difficult language [1](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/ar-eng1.htm), which is why sites like this exist. Unfortunately, I do not think a list/book/dictionary that has the information you desire exists in an easy format. A reference dictionary like the [OED](http://www.oed.com/) could help, but practice is the best teacher.

Comment: You're confusing senses 3a and 3b below: 
3.
a. An office or position of authority, such as a professorship.
b. A person who holds an office or a position of authority, such as one who presides over a meeting or administers a department of instruction at a college; a chairperson. [AHD] 3b is a concrete sense: 'The chair[person] presided over the meeting.' 'Tolkien held the Chair of English Language and Medieval Literature' is a valid example of an abstract sense.

Comment: There is a philosophical (and psycholinguistic) complication as well as the different polysemes issue - how should 'entities?' 'concepts?' such as _silence_, _hole_, _space_, _shadow_, _heat_, _humidity_ - which are perceivable using suitable senses but hardly tangible - be classified?